# carrying $this variable outside of instance

Tags: javascript, php

I am attempting to adapt an awesome php and javascript program jcart to build a product based on selection similar to assembling a computer from dell or similar - you select 4G of Ram, a 2TB HDD and a i7 Processor and instantly the price changes and the computer's part number changes. In this instance it might look something like this: DELL-i7-4GB-2TB.

The cart gets values POSTed to the file and then displays each item individual based off of unique item id numbers.

```
<form method="post" ><fieldset style="min-height:24px;">
                    <input type="hidden" name="jcartToken" value="
                                        <?php echo $_SESSION['jcartToken'];?>" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="my-item-id" value="1" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="my-item-name" value="i716" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="my-item-price" value="5000" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="my-item-partnumber" value="716" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="my-item-qty" value="1" size="3" />


<input id="716a" type="submit" name="my-add-button" value="&nbsp" class="add" 
style="float:left;"/></form>
```

I have assigned each component a part number which displays in the line item portion of the cart, like this:

```
foreach($this->get_contents() as $item) {

echo tab(7) . "<input type='hidden' id='jcartItempartnumber-{$item['id']}' 
              name='jcartItempartnumber[]' value='{$item['partnumber']}' />
              Part Number: {$item['partnumber']} \n";
              }
```

So each line item accepts and removes the Part Numbers without issue. The issue becomes That I can't put these part numbers down in the footer of the cart itself with the subtotal.

```
echo tab(7) . "<span id='jcart-subtotal'>Cost: <strong>$currencySymbol" . 
number_format($this->subtotal, $priceFormat['decimals'], $priceFormat['dec_point'], 
$priceFormat['thousands_sep']) . "</strong></span>\n";
```

Is there an easy way to display the unique part numbers down below? Ideally I would love to be able to order them based on ID number, but if it is easier for me to give each item a unique variable for the part number that's totally ok too.

Thanks in advance for any help I can get.